# WxPython: How do i add a button next to a Node in a Tree

Tags: wxpython, python-3.10

I've just started working with WxPython (GUI for Python).

My plan is to make a small task executor, where I construct a tree with task and then assign a button next to the task in the tree to execute said task.

I found that I have to use CustomTreeCtrl to achieve this, however, I can't seem to figure out how to make the button work. It's added and shows up when I execute my code but vanishes when I click on it and also the event is not triggered.

I would also like to know if there is a more controlled way to add this functionality.

Code below:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl import CustomTreeCtrl

Test_cases = {'Test_1':['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3'], 'Test_2':['Task 1', 'Task 2']}


class TreePanel(wx.Panel):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self._tree   = TaskTree(self)
    self._button_CON = wx.Button(parent=self, label='Consol')
    self._button_CON.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._execute_consol)

    self._button_GUI = wx.Button(parent=self, label='GUI')
    self._button_GUI.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._execute_gui)

    sizer_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer_h = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_h.Add(self._button_CON, 1)
    sizer_h.Add(self._button_GUI, 1)
    sizer_v.Add(self._tree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    sizer_v.Add(sizer_h, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_v)


  def _execute_consol(self, event):
    print('Running in consol mode')

  def _execute_gui(self, event):
    print('Running in gui mode')


class TaskTree(CustomTreeCtrl):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__(parent, agwStyle=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)

    self.root = self.AddRoot('Root')

    for tc_name, tc_tasks in Test_cases.items():
      NodeParent = self.AppendItem(self.root, tc_name)
      for tc_task in tc_tasks:
        panel    = wx.Panel(parent, size=(100,25))
        button   = wx.Button(parent=panel, size=(100,25), label='run')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._testButtonEvent)
        self.AppendItem(NodeParent, tc_task, wnd=panel)

    # Expand whole tree
    self.Expand(self.root)

  def _testButtonEvent(self, event):
    print('test')


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(parent=None, title='Task Executor',  size=(400,500))
    TreePanel(self)
    self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App(redirect=False)
  frame = MainFrame()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Regards

Comment: It appears to work on python3.8.10, wxPython 4.2.1, Linux, so it looks like it might be a glitch on whatever variant you are using.

Comment: I running it on windows. That might be the reason. same version 4.2.1